# How to get good results with GAN and some thousands of images?

Tags: generative-model, generative-adversarial-networks

I'm trying to generate images at minimum of size 128 x 128 with a Generative Adversarial Network. I already tried a SAGAN pytorch implementation, but I'm not very happy with results. The images look cool but and I see some correct shape but without explanation you wouldn't know what the images are about. I have a dataset of 4000 images. Lightness, colors and shapes vary a lot, but they are similar in style and on what they portray.

- With a Google Cloud V100 GPU the GAN would run a week to two with default parameters. Does this sound realistic time for this kind of dataset? It's definitely not feasible for me.
- Is 4000 images enough to train a GAN from scratch?
- Is there any implementation with pytorch/keras that would be good to get nice results with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With a Google Cloud V100 GPU the GAN would run a week to two with
>   default parameters. Does this sound realistic time for this kind of
>   dataset? It's definitely not feasible for me.

Yes, V100s are quite beefy. You shouldn't even need a week. Obviously this is based on my experience with various problems, rather than a concrete calculation.

> Is 4000 images enough to train a GAN from scratch?

For the size you want to generate, it is still on the edge of what would constitute a decent training set. You will get some results(depending on architecture) but will probably want to grab more data if at all possible.

> Is there any implementation with pytorch/keras that would be good to
>   get nice results with?

I would check out this link: https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN. It has some nice implementations in Keras. As far as the particular GAN to use, I would start out with a vanilla GAN that fits your purposes and focus on toying with hyperparameters, and if that doesn't work, look into one of the other variations that correlate well with your problem.